# Can not deploy website on microsoft azure "Server Error in '/' Application."

Tags: c#, json, azure, asp.net-core

I had my site deployed on azure and it was working fine. But a few days ago I want to upgrade my version of beta in project.json.

Before it there was beta5 and I changed it to beta8. But when I deployed it on azure - it broke my site. It was loading for a long time and nothing happened. Then I tried to return changes. I changed all for beta5, but now I had "Server Error in '/' Application.". I tried all beta-versions, but I had always same result. When I start site localy - it works perfect...Here you can see this site [broken site](http://headworks.com.ua/)

I use Visual Studio 2015. Lang - C#.

My project.json:

```
  {
  "packExclude": "*.cmd",
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
        "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.RequestContainer": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",
        "mongocsharpdriver": "2.0.0-*"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5501",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {}
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "bundleExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

My Startup.cs:

```
namespace HeadWorks_Server
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }


        // Configure is called after ConfigureServices is called.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
        {

            // Add the following to the request pipeline only in development environment.
            if (string.Equals(env.EnvironmentName, "Development", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                //app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
                //app.UseDatabaseErrorPage(DatabaseErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
            }
            else
            {
                // Add Error handling middleware which catches all application specific errors and
                // send the request to the following path or controller action.
                app.UseErrorHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{language}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", language = "ru" });
                routes.MapRoute("NotFound", "{*url}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Error" });
            });
            app.Use (async (context, next) =>
            {
                // Wrap and buffer response body.
                // Expect built in support for this at some point. The current code is prerelease
                var buffer = new MemoryStream();
                var stream = context.Response.Body;
                context.Response.Body = buffer;
                await next();

                GZipStream gstream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal);

                context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", new string[] { "gzip" });

                buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await buffer.CopyToAsync(gstream);
                gstream.Dispose();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Why it can be? How I can display the reasons of errors if I don't have web.config?

Comment: It's way easier to find the root cause once you've the actual error message. Can you turn off the custom error message, or alternative look into the logs of your application in the azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

To display the error information, you actually have that code commented out.

Above you have

```
app.UseErrorHandler("/Home/Error");
```

However instead try

```
app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
```

Note that ASP.NET 5 is now in Release Candidate stage - it may be best to update to latest and try again.